# In EF Core, how to solve an Include ThenInclude chain circular reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

Consider the following scenario. I have 3 classes, representing a many-to-many (N-to-N) relationship between Student and Subject:

```
public class Student
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public long RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Grade
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; } 
}
```

```
public class Subject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve the list of all students, with their grades, for each subject. To do so, I use:

```
// context being DbContext
var res = context.Student.Include(s => s.Grades).ThenInclude(g => g.Subject);
```

As properties are lazy-loaded, I expected each subject to only contain their "Name" property. However, upon inspection, I found that the "Grades" list is also set, with a list of all the grades assigned to the subject. This, of course, causes an object cycle.


I want to avoid that circular referencing, i.e. obtain a list where each subject's only set property is "Name". How can I do it?

Comment: Use the select statement to retrieve grades and subject  for that user.

Comment: @Jawad but then I'd have to do custom assignment. Another option would be to use manual joins, as Holger suggested, but I'm was asking for a solution using navigation properties.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid the circular reference? Is this for JSON serialisation? 1) return a view instead of the raw database objects. 2) filter the navigation properties using attributes or serialisation options. 3) null out the navigations after loading...

Answer (score 1):

If you use asp.net core 3.0 MVC/Web API, just follow below steps to overcome circular reference using `NewtonsoftJson`.

1.Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package(version depends on your project)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0
```

2.Add below code in startup

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
        {
            x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually select the name only, like

```
   context.Student.Select(x => x.Name);
```

But this does not work with the Navigation properties and the automaticly generated Joins between the tables. There it's 'all or nothing'.

Or you have to do the join completly manually, without navigation properties.

But your structure isn't that complicated and not vulnerable to circularities.
Just start of with the Grade, with the anchor element in the middle.

```
  context.Grade.Include(x => Subject).Include(x =>Student)
```

This is at least the easier way to load your entire structure and may be an approach for a starting point for manual joins.

Maybe you add a

```
   .GroupBy(x => x.Student)
```

To get closer to your list of students.

You cannot skip the "loading" of the collection, cause it's the grades, that is loaded first. So first there are the elements of the collection, than there is the subject entity. It makes no sense not to put the data in the collection.

Comment: You're suggesting selecting all of the students' names. Maybe I didn't express myself correctly, but I want to obtain a list of all the students, where each student will have a list of their grades, with the name of the subject of each grade accessible by said grade's Subject property. And I'm asking if there is any way to do this wihout using manual join, i.e. by preventing the loading of the grades to happen at the Subject level.

Comment: Yes, I understood this, and tell you, there isn't such a way. With the include you skip the lazy loading, and do immediate loading. The "include" turns lazy-loading off - that's the meaning of it. Of course you can use the lazy loading  and just access the subject. This works nice and is easy. But this will raise one query per subject item. It's not the best peformance.

Comment: Added something to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jawad's advice, I ended up using LINQ Select statements.

First, I wrote some DTO's:

```
public class StudentDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public long RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GradeDTO> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class GradeDTO
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentDTO Student { get; set; }
    public virtual SubjectDTO Subject { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class SubjectDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<GradeDTO> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var res = from student in context.Student
          select new StudentDTO
          {
              Name = student.Name,
              Birthday = student.Birthday,
              RegistrationNumber = student.RegistrationNumber,
              Grades = from grade in student.Grades
                       select new GradeDTO
                       {
                           Value = grade.Value,
                           Subject = new SubjectDTO
                           {
                               Name = grade.Subject.Name
                           }
                       }
          };
```